# I'm not able to scrape table data using selenium and beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've went as far as I can go but I can't seem to scrape data from a table.  I've searched through stackoverflow for answers but nothing seems to work.  Essentially the table comes up empty or I simply can't find elements within the table. I'm working with a table from yahoo's daily fantasy webpage.

NOTE: the current web address used will likely change week to week so it may not be a valid address in the future.

Current Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://sports.yahoo.com/dailyfantasy/contest/5416455/setlineup")

response = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,"data-tst-player-id")))
driver.quit

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
with open('test.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    f_out.write(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no element with the class-name or id that you are providing in the line

```py
response = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,"data-tst-player-id")))
```

there is however, some  tags with the attribute 'data-tst', so you can use that to make sure your page has loaded, and on this line

```py
driver.quit
```

you are doing nothing, you have to call the function driver.quit().
working code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://sports.yahoo.com/dailyfantasy/contest/5416455/setlineup")
wait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[data-tst]")))
response=driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
with open('test.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    f_out.write(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: In my code I think part of my problem is that I used `TAG_NAME`.  `data-tst-player-id` is an attribute specified in the first table row.  I attempted to use your code but it didn't work.  I got a `TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()`. Plus correct me if I'm wrong but data-tst might be getting the page before the table is actually rendered since that selector is used all over the place. I was trying to use something specific to the table.

Comment: I got it to work finally. After waiting for `By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[data-tst-player-id]"` I added `raw_page = driver.page_source` on the next line and passed that into BeautifulSoup. I now see the table information.

Comment: as i can see, you used some parts of my solution and worked, could you mark as correct solution?

Comment: Sure thing since it led me to the correct answer.  Thank you